# "Access key does not exist" when generating pre-signed S3 URL from Lambda function

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to generate a presigned URL from within a Lambda function, to get an existing S3 object .

(The Lambda function runs an ExpressJS app, and the code to generate the URL is called on one of its routes.)

I'm getting an error "*The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.*" when I visit the generated URL, though, and Google isn't helping me:

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
<Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAJ4LNLEBHJ5LTJZ5A</AWSAccessKeyId>
<RequestId>DKQ55DK3XJBYGKQ6</RequestId>
<HostId>IempRjLRk8iK66ncWcNdiTV0FW1WpGuNv1Eg4Fcq0mqqWUATujYxmXqEMAFHAPyNyQQ5tRxto2U=</HostId>
</Error>
```

The Lambda function is defined via [AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html) and given bucket access via the predefined [S3CrudPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-template-list.html#s3-crud-policy) template:

```
ExpressLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: ExpressJSApp
      Description: Main website request handler
      CodeUri: ../lambda.zip
      Handler: lambda.handler
      [SNIP]
      Policies:
        - S3CrudPolicy:
            BucketName: my-bucket-name
```

The URL is generated via the AWS SDK:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {

    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
        region: 'eu-west-1',
        signatureVersion: 'v4'
    });
    const params = {
        'Bucket': 'my-bucket-name',
        'Key': 'my-file-name'
    };
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, (error, url) => {
        res.send(`<p><a href="${url}">${url}</a></p>`)
    });
});
```

What's going wrong? Do I need to pass credentials explicitly when calling `getSignedUrl()` from within a Lambda function? Doesn't the function's execute role supply those? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Hi! Could you find a solution to this? I'm heavily interested, 'cause I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: Does the Lambda function actually have AWS credentials (via IAM role configuration)?

Comment: Just use: `const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);`

Comment: The problem is not coming up, when generating the URL, but when you try to use the generated presigned URL.

Answer (score 2):

**tldr; Go sure, to have the correct order of signature_v4 headers/formdata, in your request.**

I had the same exact issue.

I am not sure if this is the solution for everyone who is encountering the problem, but I learned the following:

The error message, and other misleading error messages can occur, if you don't use the correct order of security headers. In my case I was using the endpoint to create a presigned url, for posting a file, to upload it. In this case, you need to go sure, that you are having the correct order of security relevant data in your form-data. For signatureVersion 's3v3' it is:

- key
- x-amz-algorithm
- x-amz-credential
- x-amz-date
- policy
- x-amz-security-token
- x-amz-signature

In the special case of a POST-Request to a presigned url, to upload a file, it's important to have your file, **AFTER** the security data.

After that, the request works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I can't say for certain but I'm guessing this may have something to do with you using the old SDK. Here it is w/ v3 of the SDK. You may need to massage it a little more.

```
const { getSignedUrl } = require("@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner");
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
// ...
const client = new S3Client({ region: 'eu-west-1' });
const params = {
    'Bucket': 'my-bucket-name',
    'Key': 'my-file-name'
};
const command = new GetObjectCommand(params);
getSignedUrl(client, command(error, url) => {
    res.send(`<p><a href="${url}">${url}</a></p>`)
});
```