# S3 direct upload using a Pre-signed url generated from STS temporary credentials

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, assume-role

I am trying to upload files to s3 using a pre-signed URL. I could successfully generate the URL using the AssumeRole credential but while uploading the file from Browser it is throwing the below error.

```
<Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
    <Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
```

**Method1:**

Code used to generate presigned URL

```
cred = Aws::AssumeRoleCredentials.new(role_arn: ENV['AWS_ROLE_ARN'], role_session_name: 'xxx_service').credentials
post = Aws::S3::PresignedPost.new(creds, S3_REGION, S3_BUCKET, {
        key: Rails.env + '/' + file_name,
        metadata: {
          'original-filename' => file_name
        },
        acl: 'private',
      })

 url =  post.url,
 fields =  post.fields
```

Frontend Code to upload file from Browser

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("key", "demo/test.xxx");
form.append("x-amz-meta-original-filename", "test.xxx");
form.append("policy", "XXXXXX");
form.append("x-amz-credential", "AXXXXXXX");
form.append("x-amz-algorithm", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256");
form.append("x-amz-date", "20230530T145924Z");
form.append("x-amz-signature", "4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
form.append("file", fileInput.files[0], "test.xxx");
form.append("x-amz-security-token", "IQXXXXXXXXXXX");

var settings = {
  "url": "https://bucket-url",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "processData": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "contentType": false,
  "data": form
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

The same code was working using the IAM user credential. Due to CyberSecurity requirements, we have started using the AssumeRole credential. Even I tried adding `x-amz-session-token` in the request body but no difference in the output.

Later I found one more way to generate the pre-signed URL which is allowing me to upload file successfully from Brower using the PUT method.

**Method2:**

```
signer = Aws::S3::Presigner.new(credentails: creds, region: S3_REGION)
url, _ = signer.presigned_request(
            :put_object, bucket: S3_BUCKET, key: "#{Rails.env}/#{file_name}"
          )
```

Frontend Code to upload file from Browser

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("file", fileInput.files[0], "test.xxx");

var settings = {
  "url": "https://bucket-url/demo/Sunspot.xxx?X-Amz-Algorithm=XXXXX&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXX&X-Amz-Date=20230530T144029Z&X-Amz-Security-Token=XXXXX%3",
  "method": "PUT",
  "timeout": 0,
  "processData": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "contentType": false,
  "data": form
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

The only problem with the above solution is I am not able to reparse file **.xxx** after downloading it from S3. I have tested this solution by uploading PDF and PNG images, it opens properly after downloading it. Maybe S3 modifies the signature/hash of the file **.xxx** in the second method due to which I am not able to reparse the file. Using the first method and IAM credential, it is working fine.

Is there any other way to upload files directly to S3 from Browser without using IAM user credentials?

Comment: A couple of things: what do you mean by "reparse" the file? And aren't you able to store the AWS information in the ruby part? It looks strange to have it public in the frontend part, but that could be ok in some cases.

Comment: File Data is stored in a certain format and uploaded to s3 by the user. Once the file is uploaded to our app, we are parsing it to process the data. This parse mechanism will fail if the MD5 hash of the original file is not matching with the uploaded file. We are not storing any AWS cred in Frontend. Frontend requests for a pre-signed URL to upload the File to S3 and constructs the form using the same url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could upload the file using the Presigned POST mechanism itself. Just changing the order of the form data in the frontend code worked for me. Aws error message was misleading, instead of asking us to send the security fields in the correct order it is telling us **AccessKEY** is not found. I just interchanged the position of `x-amz-signature` and `x-amz-security-token`

Working code

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("key", "demo/test.xxx");
form.append("x-amz-meta-original-filename", "test.xxx");
form.append("policy", "XXXXXX");
form.append("x-amz-credential", "AXXXXXXX");
form.append("x-amz-algorithm", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256");
form.append("x-amz-date", "20230530T145924Z");
form.append("x-amz-signature", "4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
form.append("file", fileInput.files[0], "test.xxx");
form.append("x-amz-security-token", "IQXXXXXXXXXXX");

var settings = {
  "url": "https://bucket-url",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "processData": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "contentType": false,
  "data": form
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

We need to send security fields in the correct order while uploading files to S3.

- key
- x-amz-algorithm
- x-amz-credential
- x-amz-date
- policy
- x-amz-security-token
- x-amz-signature

I found this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578605/access-key-does-not-exist-when-generating-pre-signed-s3-url-from-lambda-functi)

Answer (score 0):

If by *reparse* the file you refer to obtaining it again from the S3 bucket, I think you need to get it by using a presigned URL:

```rb
client = ::Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'the-region')
bucket = client.bucket('the-bucket')
object = bucket.object('the-object-name-in-bucket')
filename = 'filename-as-to-be-downloaded'

presigned_url = object.presigned_url(
  :get, 
  expires_in: 300.seconds, 
  response_content_disposition: "attachment; filename=#{filename}"
)
```

Then you just obtain the file from that URL, and transform it as needed.

---

**UPDATE**: transforming as needed an image with `ChunkyPNG`:

```rb
uri = URI.parse(presigned_url)
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.use_ssl = use_ssl
https.open_timeout = 5
https.ssl_timeout = 5

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)
downloaded = response.body

image = ChunkyPNG::Image.from_blob(downloaded)
```

---

`300.seconds` may be rails-specific, which I'm not sure you're using, but that's the idea.